# Tomcat running in Docker container (Debian host) not reachable from the host

Tags: docker, tomcat, port, docker-run

I followed the instructions on Docker Hub for the tomcat image (https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat)

So I pulled the image

```
docker pull tomcat:9.0
```

and started it as described

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:9.0
```

According to the docs, this should show a 404 error page from Tomcat on the host machine when opening http://localhost:8888

But instead the browser keeps loading and eventually times out.

What am I missing here? From `docker inspect` I can see that the container exposes the port

```
        "Config": {
            ...
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            ...
         }
```

EDIT:

Container is running

```
thomas@debian:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND             CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
6f937cf0ea93   tomcat:9.0   "catalina.sh run"   3 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:8888->8080/tcp, :::8888->8080/tcp   angry_burnell
```

Output of running `curl -v http://localhost:8888`

```
thomas@debian:~$ curl -v http://localhost:8888
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8888...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8888 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8888
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I'm expecting to get 404

Comment: Have you tried to use curl? I have tried it and I get a 404 page

Comment: Both curl and wget are sending the request but waiting endlessly for a response before timing out

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no, I'm not. Just a plain VM. Running a nodejs container with exposed port works fine on the same VM

Comment: When I install tomcat directly on the host, it works fine and is also reachable, responding with a 404

Comment: Is there something elese listen on port 8888?

Comment: No, not at all. As soon as I stop the container and try to open localhost:8888 again, it immediately fails (not waiting for any timeout). I also tried changing to a completely different never before used port, to no avail

Comment: Can you share then output of `curl -v http://localhost:8888`?

Comment: see latest edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256757/discussion-between-jens-and-devnull69).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like VMWare messed things up

After reverting back to an earlier snapshot and then back to the latest one, everything started to work just fine